# How to add fonts while creating a new theme for the storefront in hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to create a new theme in hybris for the storefront. After running the commamd:

```
    ant yacceleratorstorefront_responsive_theme_setup -DsourceThemeCode=alpha -DtargetThemeCode=code1
```

I have got two folders code1 and theme-code1. theme-code1 has only images and code1 has fonts and less folders. Can someone please guide where should I add new fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Try

1. Find path Your_storefront\web\webroot\WEB-INF_ui-src\responsive\themes\code1\fonts\ . Put your fonts there.
   You may need to add less/css file for icon font and import it in main style.less file. If it doesn't have it's own less/css - add font-face rule  someshere in less.
2. Rebuild project (I used "ant clean all"). Your fonts must appear in Your_storefront\web\webroot_ui\responsive\theme-code1\fonts
   Don't forget to check or correct path to the font in less/css or it'll not be found in a browser.

You may also need to check font paths in Gruntfile.js